# Alternative for the Class diagram

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

Can anyone suggest me an alternative diagram for this ? I'm just confused with this question..

[image]

Comment: This is fairly simple - what don't you understand?

Comment: @AlvinBunk I've represented that hierarchy using a class diagram. But what is the alternative diagram ?

Comment: I think you should create a class diagram with different classes and put this in contrast to the given diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative could just add things that you haven't included in the original, for example I can suggest instead of just 'changeTime' method to the Clock class, add a 'setTime' or a constructor that initializes the Clock. Then you need to explain why that differences would be better.
This is my example, but I think you could add a few more things, just explain why it's better or worse than the original.
Ok, here's an example class, I've drawn it roughly...

```
Clock
_____
# hour:byte
# minute:byte
# second:byte
____________
+changeTime(hour:byte,minute:byte,second:byte)
-setTime(hour:byte,minute:byte,second:byte)

^
|
|

Travel Clock
...
```

Now, you tell me why it's better - definitely it's better.
Made `setTime` private, so it's for initialization and internal use only.

Comment: Okay, So the questions asking for a different/modified version of the same diagram? or the completely different type of a diagram?

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: What's the difference between setTime and the changeTime ?

Comment: I edited the diagram. Now there's a difference in that `setTime` is private, and it's used for initialization. By the way, I'm only giving you examples of how the diagrams might be different; I would expect that you would do a better job than what I've shown. Do you understand why using 'byte' is better?

Comment: Ok, can you mark my answer as the correct answer (I think it is) then? Thanks!

Comment: The question is poorly worded (it should say "alternative class diagram" instead of "alternative diagram"), and it's understandable that CR7 got confused.  Someone could have, for example, represented the exact same classes object diagram and explained why Class is a better diagram to use than object.